# Creating subfolders (Power Automate)

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I currently have a flow which creates folders on SharePoint based on cell values within an excel table which updates every day, I now need 5 sub-folders to automatically be created every time a folder is created from the previous flow mentioned.

For e.g., the excel table contains account numbers, the flow I have created runs every day creating a folder for each account number, I now need sub folders called -> Contracts/Quotes/Remittance Advices/Stock/General to be created every time a new account folder is made.

Comment: You just need to dynamically get the new path and add folders within the new path

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Create a excel file and format as table.

2.Upload the excel file to SharePoint Documents library

[image]

3.Create a Microsoft Flow

[image]

4.Save and Test this flow

5.When you update the excel file, you will see the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]